# wzip.c OS three easy steps

Tags: c, operating-system

I am newbie in OS. Im currently learning OS three easy steps.
I found this code for the the first project of the course.
(wzip) is a file compression tool, and the other (wunzip) is a file decompression tool.

**input:**
aaaaaaaaaabbbb

**correct output:**
10a4b

instructions: write out a 4-byte integer in binary format followed by the single character in ASCII.

**current output:**

ab

---

I type in the shell:

```
prompt> gcc -o wzip wzip.c -Wall -Werror
prompt> ./wzip file1.txt > file1.z
```

---

This is the link for the project:
https://github.com/remzi-arpacidusseau/ostep-projects/tree/master/initial-utilities

---

This is the code I found for this specific part of the project:

wzip:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

/* 
wzip: is a file compresion tool.

*/

void writeFile(int , char *);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    FILE *fp;
    char newbuff[2], oldbuff[2];
    int count;

    if (argc < 2){
        printf("wzip: file1 [file2 ...]\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // open files
    for (size_t i = 1; i < argc; i++){
        if ((fp = fopen(argv[i], "r")) == NULL){
            printf("wzip: cannot open file\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        while (fread(newbuff, 1, 1, fp)){
            if (strcmp(newbuff, oldbuff) == 0){
                count++;
            } else {
                if (oldbuff[0] != '\0'){
                    writeFile(count, oldbuff);
                }
                count = 1;
                strcpy(oldbuff, newbuff);
            }
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }
    writeFile(count, oldbuff);
    return 0;
}

void writeFile(int count, char *oldbuff){

    // write as network byte order
    count = htonl(count);
    fwrite(&count, 4, 1, stdout);
    fwrite(oldbuff, 1, 1, stdout);
}
```

wunzip:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>    // exit
#include <string.h>    // memset
#include <arpa/inet.h> // ntohl

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *fp;
    char buff[5];

    if (argc <= 1) {
        printf("wunzip: file1 [file2 ...]\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (size_t i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        if ((fp = fopen(argv[i], "r")) == NULL) {
            printf("wunzip: cannot open file\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        int count = 0;
        while (fread(&count, 4, 1, fp)) {
            count = ntohl(count);    // read from network byte order
            memset(buff, 0, strlen(buff));
            fread(buff, 1, 1, fp);
            for (size_t i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                printf("%s", buff);
            }
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Cant please some one can give a hand to understand better.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please narrow it down to a specific problem you are having.

Comment: Consider invoking your run script with `./test-wzip.sh -h` to get help message. That should get you started.

Comment: I think my problem is that I dont understanding what its htonl(count) and ntohl(count) are actually doing . when I test ./test-wunzip.sh: I having an infinity loop

Answer (score 1):

How is your solution coming along?

The first that jumps out about the code posted here is that your write the wrong number of bytes. In other words, you don't follow the compression guidelines of the exercise. The instructions for the OSTEP project was to write a 32 bit int (4 bytes) followed by a single ascii character (1 byte).

It helps to set up a test before writing the compressed output. Make sure that what is being written does indeed equal 5 bytes.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct token {
    u_int32_t count;
    u_int8_t ch;
};

size_t numbytes (struct token t) {
    /* calculates the number of bytes in a single token */
    /* assumes a token has two attributes */
    /* should return a value of 5 */
    size_t mybytes = sizeof(t.count) + sizeof(t.ch)
    return mybytes;
}
```

I personally found it easier to think about the read procedure in terms of a parser. This is due to the fact that some of the test cases get slightly more complex. You need to effectively manage state between line reads and also between files.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little bit late, but I just did this program for my course's assignment and I want to share my solution. It passes all the available test cases but it's not official from any party (neither from my course nor the project owner).

The code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>  // FILE, stdout, fprintf, fwrite, fgetc, EOF, fclose
#include <stdlib.h> // EXIT_*, exit

struct rle_t
{
    int l;
    char c;
};

void
writerle(struct rle_t rleobj)
{
    fwrite((int *)(&(rleobj.l)), sizeof(int), 1, stdout);
    fwrite((char *)(&(rleobj.c)), sizeof(char), 1, stdout);
}

struct rle_t
process(FILE *stream, struct rle_t prev)
{
    int curr;
    struct rle_t rle;

    while ((curr = fgetc(stream)) != EOF)
    {
        if (prev.c != '\0' && curr != prev.c)
        {
            rle.c  = prev.c;
            rle.l  = prev.l;
            prev.l = 0;

            writerle(rle);
        }

        prev.l++;
        prev.c = curr;
    }

    rle.c = prev.c;
    rle.l = prev.l;

    return rle;
}

int
main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        fprintf(stdout, "wzip: file1 [file2 ...]\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    struct rle_t prev;
    prev.c = '\0';
    prev.l = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i)
    {

        FILE *fp = fopen(argv[i], "r");

        if (fp == NULL)
        {
            fprintf(stdout, "wzip: cannot open files\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        struct rle_t rle = process(fp, prev);
        prev.c           = rle.c;
        prev.l           = rle.l;

        fclose(fp);
    }

    writerle(prev);

    return 0;
}
```

From the post, I think there is no need to use any function like [`htonl(3)`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/htonl) for this problem. The tricky part is in the `writerle()` function, which you already got it. But let me explain what I understand:

- Use [`fwrite(3)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fwrite.3p.html) to write binary format to the stream, in this case, `stdout`.
- First parameter is a pointer, that's why I need `&(rleobj.l)` and `&(rleobj.c)`.
- This line

```c
fwrite((int *)(&(rleobj.l)), sizeof(int), 1, stdout);
```

tells that I want to write 4 bytes (`sizeof(int)`) of the first parameter              (`&(rleobj.l)`) to the standard output (`stdout`) one time (`1`). The typecast is **optional** (depending on your compiler and how you want to read your code).

The reason why they require you to do so is because it will separate between the run-length part and the character part.

Let's say you have a simple input file like this:

```
333333333333333333333333333333333aaaaaaaaaaaa
```

After encoding without the binary format:

```
33312a
```

This is wrong. Because now, it looks like the run-length of the character `a` is 33312, instead of 33 of `3` and 12 of `a`.

However, with binary format, those parts are separated:

```bash
❯ xxd -b output.z
00000000: 00100001 00000000 00000000 00000000 00110011 00001100  !...3.
00000006: 00000000 00000000 00000000 01100001                    ...a
```

Here, the first four bytes represent the run-length and the next one byte represents the character.

I hope this will help.